# MOSS SQL Query failing in Sharepoint 2010 with Invalid Column error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have this query that I am trying to make work in SharePoint 2010.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (UI.tp_Login) AS UI_tp_Login, AUD.nvarchar9 AS AUD_UniqueID 
FROM AllUserData AS AUD WITH (NOLOCK) FULL OUTER JOIN 
UserInfo AS UI WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON AUD.tp_SiteId = UI.tp_SiteID AND AUD.tp_ID = UI.tp_ID 
WHERE AUD.tp_DirName like N'%/_catalogs/users' 
AND NOT (AUD.tp_ContentType = 'DomainGroup') 
AND NOT (AUD.tp_ContentType = 'SharePointGroup') 
AND (AUD.nvarchar3 NOT IN ('SHAREPOINT\system','NT AUTHORITY\local service'))
```

I am getting error invalid column name 'tp_DirName', 'tp_ContentType'.

Looks like SP 2010 database scheme has changed.

I don't have access to the database to I can't see the schema.

Does anyone know what are the new names of these 2 columns in SP 2010?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

it is not recommended to directly access sharepoint managed databases. You can access all the data you require using sharepoint object model.

Comment: accessing the SP database directly is bad practice and should not be done. Find a way around it.

Comment: yes it is not advisable but if I want to try this out do you have any idea how can we do this?\

Answer (score 0):

'tp_ContentType' is no more, now is 'tp_ContentTypeId'
corresponding ids:
'0x010B00C7BCF68683E2A64B99CD9B275AEA5859' - sharepoint group
'0x010A00D2995B358A1FA54FBB5D4C473FA55C4B' - domain group
can't find any simular to 'tp_DirName'